# rsync + chmod only selected files

Tags: permissions, rsync, chmod

I'm trying to sync specific cron files between 2 servers and change the permissions for them. However, the command I am trying is also changing the permissions on the main directory.

Command used:

```
rsync -ai --no-o --no-g --chmod=644 --delete --include='ccron_*' --exclude='*' /etc/ccrons/ root@worker:/etc/cron.d/
```

That causes the directory `/etc/cron.d` on the destination machine to have the permissions 644 as well.

It works when I add wildcard to the source folder (`/etc/ccrons/*`) but then `--delete` doesn't work and files that were deleted in the source are not deleted in the destination.

I'm using rsync 3.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: If you are not transferring subdirs, my rsync allows `--chmod=F644` to only affect file permissions.

Comment: Thanks @meuh. Actually I went to manual and read that right after I posted this thread. -_-. This works for me. I had to add D755 as well to keep the permissions as it was on /etc/cron.d. Luckily I don't have sub-folders.